Ошибка CS0104 при создании таймера в WinForms
При написании вручную (не через toolbox) таймера в Winforms возникает ошибка CS0104: 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer'
Насколько я понимаю, компилятор обращает внимание, что таймер есть как в пространстве имён System.Windows.Forms так и в пространстве имён System.Threading и надо из этого выбрать что-то одно (например так: using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;).
Но дело в том, что в usings пространство имён System.Threading  у меня не подключено (есть только System.Threading.Tasks).
Тогда почему возникает такая ошибка?

Определение глобальных пространств в отдельном файле.

@EvgeniyZ то есть System.Threading у меня где-то подключен в качестве глобального пространства имён и  я это просто не вижу?

Выключить Implicit usings https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/

Да, в современных проектах .NET, если вы не выбрали соответствующую опцию при создании проекта, у вас будут использоваться заранее прописанные глобальные пространства имен, объекты которого будут доступны в любом месте вашего проекта. Вот и получается, что у вас конфликт подключенного вами System.Windows.Forms и глобальным System.Threading.
